# What does "reduce delta to ubuntu" mean?

Tags: apt

In [Accepted apt 1.0.3 (source all amd64)](http://packages.qa.debian.org/a/apt/news/20140505T153433Z.html), this appears:

```
Changes: 
 apt (1.0.3) unstable; urgency=medium
 .
   [ Michael Vogt ]
   * reduce delta to ubuntu
   * provide support for vendor specific config files
   * debian/apt-doc.docs: remove README.MultiArch
   * Fix missing ScreenWidth check in apt.cc
   * Only do openpty() if both stdin/stdout are terminals (Closes: 746434)
 .
```

So what does "reduce delta to ubuntu" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really about Ubuntu as such but *delta* is used to mean the distance or difference between two things. Presumably, the log you quote describes changes made in Debian's `apt` package to make it more similar to changes implemented downstream by the Ubuntu developers.

*Delta* is used here with this definition ([source](https://www.wordnik.com/words/delta)):

> The set of differences between two versions of a file.

Comment: I didn't ask for the meaning of the word but of the phrase and in the context I encountered it. Anyway, thanks for offering an answer.

Comment: @DKBose Sorry, I thought that answered you. Is it still unclear? The Debian devs have apparently adopted downstream changes that were implemented by Ubuntu back into the original Debian package, thereby "reducing the delta".

Answer (score 3):

[This is the commit the message does references](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=apt/apt.git;a=commitdiff;h=6c50447eb443768764f83b3ba86ef32780ba6dde;hp=506ab3c78fb67f5e452a1748f4870af767de5ebb). There are some miscellaneous changes that benefit Ubuntu and are being incorporated to the master branch, is the case of the activation of apport reports:

```c
--- a/apt-pkg/deb/dpkgpm.cc
+++ b/apt-pkg/deb/dpkgpm.cc
@@ -1617,7 +1617,7 @@ void pkgDPkgPM::WriteApportReport(const char *pkgpath, const char *errormsg)
    string::size_type pos;
    FILE *report;

-   if (_config->FindB("Dpkg::ApportFailureReport", false) == false)
+   if (_config->FindB("Dpkg::ApportFailureReport", true) == false)
    {
       std::clog << "configured to not write apport reports" << std::endl;
       return;
```

Adding any files ending in .distUpgrade to the list of ignored:

```c
--- a/apt-pkg/init.cc
+++ b/apt-pkg/init.cc
@@ -86,6 +86,7 @@ bool pkgInitConfig(Configuration &Cnf)
    Cnf.Set("Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently::", "\\.dpkg-[a-z]+$");
    Cnf.Set("Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently::", "\\.save$");
    Cnf.Set("Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently::", "\\.orig$");
+   Cnf.Set("Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently::", "\\.distUpgrade$");

    // Default cdrom mount point
    Cnf.CndSet("Acquire::cdrom::mount", "/media/cdrom/");
```

Adding `linux-tools` to the list of packages to do not autoremove and changes to the line limit of the override file of ftp repositories (I think). The change to the `debian/apt.install.in` didn't make sense to me (maybe just a comment), so I don't know what it does.

Comment: `== false` looks like an Indian code to me. It should be `!_config->FindB("Dpkg::ApportFailureReport", true)`

Comment: @Danatela talk with Michael Vogt, he's the one that modified the sources. [Here is the context](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=apt/apt.git;a=blob;f=apt-pkg/deb/dpkgpm.cc;h=c52b83c6ee26e278f445d131d9133c930bd5e532;hb=6c50447eb443768764f83b3ba86ef32780ba6dde#l1605) but I presume he's activating apport reports on dpkg errors.

Comment: Heck, I'm sure. apt looks for `Dpkg::ApportFailureReport true` in the configuration files, if it doesn't find it, returns `false` in which case evaluates true (`false == false // true`) and executes the next piece of code that informs that apport is disabled then returns.

Comment: Yep, but `false == false` is fully equivalent to `!false`. However I would bother him only if I find a bug in his code.

Comment: @Danatela if he ask you who told you, don't ever mention my name!